# Creating a list with a slice and a return function

Tags: python, list, function, loops, sorting

**Can someone please explain why I am getting an error** 
Programming Problem:

Write a creative program as follows to demonstrate your understanding of Python lists:

Start by making an empty list.
Use a loop to add twelve random integers between 50 and 80, inclusive, to the list.
Sort the list in descending order from highest to lowest.
Use a loop to print the sorted list elements on one line separated by single spaces.
Determine if 66 is in the list and generate some appropriate output. See SAMPLE OUTPUT.
Print the largest element in the list and the smallest element in the list.
Slice out the five elements with indexes 4 through 8 and assign to a variable. Print the slice.
Print the total of all five elements in this slice.
Use a while loop to display all elements in the slice on one line separated by tabs.
SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
71 70 67 66 62 55 53 52 52 52 51 50 
Yes, 66 is in the list at index 3
71 is the largest element
The smallest element is 50
Here is the slice [62, 55, 53, 52, 52]
The total of the slice is 274
62 55 53 52 52
```

### MY code:

```
import random
def main ():
    empty_list = []
    for x in range (12):
        empty_list.append(random.randint(50,80))
        empty_list.sort(reverse=True)
    for x in empty_list:
        print(empty_list,end='')
        break  
    print ()
    print(max(empty_list),'is the largest element')
    print('The smallest element in the list is',min(empty_list))
    print('Here is the slice',empty_list[4:-3])
    print('The total of the slice is',sum(empty_list[4:-3]))
    print(empty_list[4:-3])
    index_finder(num)
    print(index_finder(num))
def index_finder(x):
    if empty_list in range(12) == 66:
       print('Yes, 66 is in the list') 
    else:
       print('No, 66 is not in the list')
    return index_finder(x) 
main()
```

****Determine if 66 is in the list and generate some appropriate output. 
I am trying to determine if 66 is in the list and generate the necessary output, but I keep getting an error. The rest of the code is correct, however for this portion of the problem it's not successfully determining if it's a number or not. In other words, determine if one of the random numbers in the list is 66. I can get it to run without errors, but it's not generating the accurate output. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: `if empty_list in range(12) == 66:` - what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Once you put something in `empty_list`, it is no longer empty, making that a REALLY bad name.

Comment: `NameError: name 'num' is not defined`. You are trying to use a variable that you haven't defined. Is `num` supposed to be 66?

Comment: You are calling `index_finder()` within `index_finder()`. That will run endlessly.

Comment: What is the not accurate output you *are* generating?

Comment: good point. I need better names for my variables. @ Scott. Essentially what I am trying to do is determine if 66 is in the random list then indicate yes or no plus the index location @ FMc

Comment: Its suppose to determine if 66 is in the list or not then indicate which index location @ scott.

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep yourself organized when writing code is to avoid
mixing of computation and printing. Here is a sketch of what
your program might look like if we follow that principle:

```
import random

def main ():

    # Create values.
    vals = []
    for x in range(12):
        vals.append(random.randint(50,80))
    vals.sort(reverse=True)

    # Compute some stuff.
    max_val = max(vals)
    min_val = min(vals)
    has_66 = 66 in vals
    vals_slice = vals[4:9]        # Elements 4 through 8, inclusive.
    sum_slice = sum(vals_slice)

    # Print stuff.
    ...

main()
```

You can also create the values more simply, using a list comprehension (probably a future topic in your Python course):

```
vals = [random.randint(50, 80) for x in range(12)]
```

Comment: Wow. That's beautifully put and will do. Way more organized.

Comment: Made the change to the program and looks a lot more organized! thanks. Side note: how long does it take to code like this or think of the code in this way? By the way, how do I output the program to say yes it has the number 66 or no.

Comment: @A.B. Not long: just keep different things separate (eg, calculation vs display/print), and be very strict about it. The same idea applies in many other areas as well. If we were doing this more fully, we would even go farther, separating values-creation, stats-calculation, and output-printing into their own functions. The `has_66` variable holds a boolean value (`True` or `False`). So you can use it in an if-else structure in the typical way: `if has_66: ...   else: ...` (indentation not shown).

Comment: @A.B. To get the index of 66, you'll need to do more calculation. You could iterate over `vals`, keeping a counter of the index yourself. You could research the `enumerate()` function. You could also use `vals.index(66)` but you would need to write code to handle the exception if 66 is not in the list.